# Does anyone have recent experience with the RGoogleDocs package?

Tags: r, google-docs

A quick search for the RGoogleDocs packages gives several old SO threads: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=rgoogledocs

Does anyone have recent experience with this package?

I have the package installed, but when I try to use it with my private Google App account I get a simple: `Error: Forbidden` message.

When I switch over to my regular Google account, the authentication step noted [here](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/run.html) works, but the `getDocs(x)` function gives:

`Error in getDocs(gcon) : 
  problems connecting to get the list of documents: Forbidden (403)`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you provided _reproducible_ code, I'd at least try to run it to see if I can replicate the error.

Comment: Gsee: I can't think of a good way to make this one reproducible since the example requires a Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? It works for me. I am not using an app account but rather a personal account. When last I tried it on an app account it worked.

```
library(RGoogleDocs)  
if(exists("ps")) print("got password, keep going") else ps <-readline(prompt="get the password in ")  #conditional password asking  
options(RCurlOptions = list(capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))  
sheets.con <- getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth("yourusername@gmail.com", ps, service ="wise"))  
data<-getWorksheets("yourspreadsheetnamehere",sheets.con)  
names(data)  
sheetofinterest <-sheetAsMatrix(data$"nameoftabehere",header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE) #Get one sheet
```

Comment: @GSee thank you for editing the code. what did you do keep each line on it own?

Comment: Ah, wonderful!  Thanks Farrel, that worked!  (At least with an @gmail account, the Google apps account still has authentication problems)

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google changed level of  security  since  Statwonk post (2012 )
Above advice  didn't solve my problem for  the same "Error: Forbidden" issue .

What led me to solution for this issue  was the alert  from Google  about Security settings.
So just ENABLE "Access for less secure apps" at
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and when you are done with R code you can put it back to DISABLE (if needed)